# Retention, Cohorts, and Visualisations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am working on Retention,cohorts and visualization to make it simple I am working reporting and analytical tools using Ruby on rails.

I am looking for a gem or something which will be useful for me.

Any pointers and headers will be good, I am newbie to rails too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should check this gem: https://github.com/n8/cohort_me